# NSColor transparency on black background?

Tags: cocoa, macos, transparency, nscolor

In the background of my view, I draw a light blue color. And in the middle, i have a square box that is supposed to have an even lighter gray in it that has a 20% transparency. But for some reason the transparency is on top of a black background instead of a blue. I'm sorry If i'm not being clear.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your `drawRect:` method, and a screenshot of what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using the wrong compositing mode to draw the smaller box.   Show us your code.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that I was supposed to be using NSRectFillUsingOperation(rect, NSCompositeSourceOver); rather than normal NSRectFill